# How can I install opencv for Python on Cloud9?

Tags: python, opencv, cloud9-ide, cloud9, c9.io

I've been wanting to work more with images, and opencv sounds like a great resource, but I can't figure out how to get it up and running in Python on Cloud9.

I've tried using the terminal commands:

```
[compiler] sudo apt-get install build-essential
[required] sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
[optional] sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

Which seemed to work until I tried to do `import cv2` and that failed with the error message "No module named cv2".

I then downloaded the latest version of opencv from sourceforge and extracted it into the folder I put my program in. Again, "No module named cv2".

How can I check to see if opencv installed correctly?
How can I get the `import cv` line to work?

Answer (score 1):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

Run [this file](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/opencv_latest.sh) in your terminal and then run this

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Comment: Should they run python-opencv command after? Maybe add that to answer.